# Electrum Litecoin keeps synchronizing. What should I do?

Tags: electrum

I got 65 ltc on my wallet. Electrum only jot down 35. I can't send money because I got error message server not responding

[image]

I transferred the seed to another electrum wallet. It works.

How do I fix my current wallet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply reinstall electrum wallet and it works.

Before that, for safety, I install electrum to another computer, use the seed key and transfer all money out to BITTREX.

HOWEVER,

**I want to caution.
My method is actually very dangerous.**

Why?

https://github.com/pooler/electrum-ltc/issues/176

Someone lost 2000 Litecoin because they download electrum wallet from a phishing site.

***Fortunately*** for me. I downloaded from the right site

If I didn't I too would have lost my litecoin.

Please check that the certificate is valid and there is a picture of padlock (green padlock) if you use firefox.

The CORRECT electrum LTC address is

https://electrum-ltc.org/

As far as I know.

You got to see the padlock picture and https:// address there.

So an answer to the question for most newbie is

Reinstall electrum ltc wallet. No need to delete wallet file or anything. Make sure you download it from the right person.

@Dan answer is also good.

However, deleting wallet, backing it up and bla bla is beyond the skill of most users of wallet.

Comment: Someone edit and add cryptonite browser plugin. I think it's a good edit. However, I think you should create another answer. I will ask a question for that.

Comment: Yeah, disregard my previous suggestions for cryptonite.  I hadn't realized they had started an ICO.  Kinda kills their credibility.

Comment: I've reverted the change as discussed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Backup the wallet file
2. Delete the electrum data directory
3. Restart electrum-ltc

Since I don't know your OS...

- Linux Data directory: `$HOME/.electrum-ltc`
- Windows Data Directory: `\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Local\Electrum-LTC`

or something very similar to those.